# Concatenate file paths to variable in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a script that I've put together that should copy the list of files to a variable but the only thing I receive is the last file. In other words, when I echo the variable in my for loop, I see 20 or so files but only the last one gets copied to my variable. How can I get them all to copy correctly?

I am using Windows 7.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

for /r %%x in (*) do (
    echo %%x
    SET PATH_VALUE=%%x;%PATH_VALUE%
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use delayed expansion. You've enabled it – half the job done. Now you only want to *use* it. Replace the `%`s around `PATH_VALUE` with `!`s and you are done:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

for /r %%x in (*) do (
    echo %%x
    SET PATH_VALUE=%%x;!PATH_VALUE!
)
```

Comment: Wow! I tried something similar to that earlier and it didn't work but that did! Thanks!